# Storing metadata of various services according to ISO 19119?

Tags: sql, web-service, metadata, iso-19119

I need to store the metadata of web services according to ISO 19119 standard.

Hence I am looking for some guidelines for designing the database for storage.

Can any one suggest any document to help in writing the SQL script

Answer (score 1):

You could try in the first instance the Metadata Data Model published by the British Geological Survey.

http://www.earthdatamodels.org/designs/metadata_BGS.html

This is really related to ISO 19115 metadata, which you mention in your tag. ISO 19119 only adds a little to the data model, that is, to hold all the metadata about your service you will need ISO 19115 + ISO 19119.